# Make a copy of a vector containing struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have made a vector called:`vector Person persons` containing objects created from the`struct Person`

```
struct Person
{
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string sign;
    float length;
};
```

Is there any quick way to make a copy of `persons* containing all its saved objects?

Comment: In your specific snippet, the compiler will implicitly declare all your special member functions for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the copy constructor:

```
vector <Person> a = { .... };   // populate a somehow
vector <Person> b( a );   // copy it
```

Comment: That was fast! Thank you! :)